# Mac - Unreal 4.24.3 - Oculus Quest - Gradle - Error: ERROR: /bin/sh failed with args -c '"/Users/.../gradle/gradlew" :app:assembleDebug'

Tags: android, macos, gradle, quest

Hello and thanks in advance,

I am trying to get started developing for the Oculus Quest using the Unreal Engine 4.24.3 on a Mac. I know, this is not the ideal setup. I have downloaded ADB and followed the steps in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmAH8-R4psE

I can see the Oculus Quest device but I run into an error when I try to deploy - "Launch Failed"

Here are the errors I encounter:

```
LogPlayLevel: Error: ERROR: /bin/sh failed with args -c '"/Users/jordanrichardson/Desktop/UNREAL/Immersiful4/Intermediate/Android/APK/gradle/gradlew" :app:assembleDebug'
LogPlayLevel: Error: RunUAT ERROR: AutomationTool was unable to run successfully.
PackagingResults: Error: Launch failed! Unknown Error
```

Here is end of the resulting log, error lines are towards the end:

```
LogPlayLevel: ====3/19/2020 7:47:37 PM====PREPARING NATIVE CODE=================================================================
LogPlayLevel: APK contains data.
LogPlayLevel: Disabling Show Launch Image for Oculus Mobile enabled application
LogPlayLevel: Copying permission_library directory to staging before build
LogPlayLevel: Directory /Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_4.24/Engine/Source/ThirdParty/AndroidPermission/permission_library copied to /Users/jordanrichardson/Desktop/UNREAL/Immersiful4/Intermediate/Android/APK/JavaLibs/permission_library
LogPlayLevel: ==== Writing to OBB data file /Users/jordanrichardson/Desktop/UNREAL/Immersiful4/Build/Android/src/com/YourCompany/Immersiful4/OBBData.java ====
LogPlayLevel: ==== OBB data file up to date so not writing. ====
LogPlayLevel: Copying vulkan layers from /Users/jordanrichardson/NVPACK/android-ndk-r14b/sources/third_party/vulkan/src/build-android/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a
LogPlayLevel: Copying libvrapi.so
LogPlayLevel: File /Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_4.24/Engine/Source/ThirdParty/Oculus/OVRPlugin/OVRPlugin/ExtLibs/armeabi-v7a/libvrapi.so copied to /Users/jordanrichardson/Desktop/UNREAL/Immersiful4/Intermediate/Android/APK/libs/armeabi-v7a/libvrapi.so
LogPlayLevel: Copying libOVRPlugin.so
LogPlayLevel: File /Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_4.24/Engine/Source/ThirdParty/Oculus/OVRPlugin/OVRPlugin/Lib/armeabi-v7a/libOVRPlugin.so copied to /Users/jordanrichardson/Desktop/UNREAL/Immersiful4/Intermediate/Android/APK/libs/armeabi-v7a/libOVRPlugin.so
LogPlayLevel: File /Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_4.24/Engine/Source/ThirdParty/Oculus/OVRPlugin/OVRPlugin/ExtLibs/VrApi.jar does not exist, not copied!
LogPlayLevel: File /Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_4.24/Engine/Source/ThirdParty/Oculus/OVRPlugin/OVRPlugin/ExtLibs/SystemUtils.jar does not exist, not copied!
LogPlayLevel: ====3/19/2020 7:47:38 PM====PERFORMING FINAL APK PACKAGE OPERATION================================================
LogPlayLevel: Copied file /Users/jordanrichardson/Desktop/UNREAL/Immersiful4/Intermediate/Android/APK/gradle/app/src/main/assets/UE4CommandLine.txt.
LogPlayLevel: Fix gradlew permissions
LogPlayLevel: Making .apk with Gradle...
LogPlayLevel: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
LogPlayLevel: * What went wrong:
LogPlayLevel: Could not determine java version from '13.0.2'.
LogPlayLevel: * Try:
LogPlayLevel: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
LogPlayLevel: * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
LogPlayLevel: Error: ERROR: /bin/sh failed with args -c '"/Users/jordanrichardson/Desktop/UNREAL/Immersiful4/Intermediate/Android/APK/gradle/gradlew" :app:assembleDebug'
LogPlayLevel:  (see /Users/jordanrichardson/Library/Logs/Unreal Engine/LocalBuildLogs/Log.txt for full exception trace)
LogPlayLevel: AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=1 (Error_Unknown)
LogPlayLevel: Completed Launch On Stage: Deploy Task, Time: 4.579098
LogPlayLevel: Error: RunUAT ERROR: AutomationTool was unable to run successfully.
PackagingResults: Error: Launch failed! Unknown Error
```